# READ_SETTINGS permission needed to launch gmaps with intent on WEAR OS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-permissions, wear-os

My Android app has to launch gmaps on Wear OS

```
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" +Uri.encode( string));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
   // mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        activity.startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```

but I get an error that says Permission denial... It wants
    com.google.android.wearable.READ_SETTINGS

If I put this

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.wearable.READ_SETTINGS" />
```

in the manifest then I get the same kind of error.

I am not able to ask for permission programmatically with something similar to this

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_SETTINGS)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("permissions","granted");
            } else {
                // Show rationale and request permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SETTINGS},
                        MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
```

because that constant is not found. It is not useful to write the complete com.google.android.wearable.READ_SETTINGS string.

I do not understand why READ_SETTINGS is needed.
How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps on wearOS cannot handle `Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" +Uri.encode( string))`  or in this format as suggested in documentation `Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain+View, California")`. While the same intent on phone launches Google Maps and shows you a list of suggestions.

My guess is that the Maps app on wearOS is meant to be lightweight , you can only search for something in a particular city or region like this:

```
// Searches for 'Main Street' near San Francisco
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=101+main+street");
```

The below link shows examples of Google Maps intents to use on Android : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

For the error:

> com.google.android.wearable.READ_SETTINGS

You don't need to add this in permissions, but check whether your wear app manifest has this :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```